# Android Studio dynamic ViewPager with dynamic buttons in every page

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-button

I have same buttons in every page and can be pressed and unpressed, but when change pages in viewpager my buttons become all unpressed.

Answer (score 0):

answer 1
You need to prevent the page from refreshing.
5 is number of your pages.

ViewPager view_pager;
view_pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

or

answer 2
you have to store buttons state